# Automating Xcode archive and upload?

Tags: xcode, command-line, app-store-connect, testflight

We have a dozen targets in the same Xcode project, each target is an app on itself, and we always release all the apps at the same time.
It extremely counterproductive to individually archive and upload each target to iTunesConnect.

I believe I've found a way to archive: http://blog.octo.com/en/automating-over-the-air-deployment-for-iphone/

But so far I was unable to find a way to upload to iTunesConnect from command line.

Please advice how should I approach this task. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `altool`, Application Loader’s command-line tool for validating and uploading your application binary files to the App Store. Please checkout [apploader](https://help.apple.com/itc/apploader/#/apdATD1E53-D1E1A1303-D1E53A1126)

Also, you can use `deliver` to submit your app for App Store review. Please checkout [master/deliver](https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/tree/master/deliver#readme)